# Asp.Net MVC 3 "Use HTML5 semantic markup" option

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have installed MVC 3 and now I'm trying to follow these steps:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

However, when I'm creating a new project:
http://i1.asp.net/asp.net/images/mvc/msv30/image014.jpg
I don't have the option 'Use HTML5 semantic markup'.

I'm using VS 2010, framework 4.0, MVC 3, just as in the example. Why don't I have that option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools update. 
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx